# Para que se usa el return false al final de una función?

Tags: javascript, es6

He visto en algunos códigos que al final de una función se coloca la expresión return false o return true, alguien me puede explicar para qué sirve que devuelva este tipo de valores.

```
self.initialize = function () {
    if ( self.initialized ) **return true**;

    self.error = '';
    self.d     = (typeof target === 'string')
      ? document.getElementById( target )
      : target;
    if ( !self.d ) {
        self.error = '[CountUp] target is null or undefined';
        **return false;**
    }
    self.startVal = Number( startVal );
    self.endVal   = Number( endVal );
    // error checks
    if ( ensureNumber( self.startVal ) && ensureNumber( self.endVal ) ) {
        self.decimals    = Math.max( 0, decimals || 0 );
        self.dec         = Math.pow( 10, self.decimals );
        self.duration    = Number( duration ) * 1000 || 2000;
        self.countDown   = (self.startVal > self.endVal);
        self.frameVal    = self.startVal;
        self.initialized = true;
        **return true;**
    }
    else {
        self.error = '[CountUp] startVal (' + startVal + ') or endVal (' + endVal + ') is not a number';
        **return false;**
    }
};
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

La instrucción `return` finaliza la ejecución de una función y especifica el valor a ser devuelto por ésta.

El valor devuelto puede ser de cualquier tipo. Por ejemplo puede haber funciones que devuelvan valores numéricos:

```js
function suma(a, b){
  return a + b;
}

console.log(suma(4,7));
```

, cadenas:

```js
function saludo(nombre){
  return 'Hola ' + nombre;
}

console.log(saludo('Cristian'));
```

, fechas, arrays, cualquier tipo de objeto,.... o, como en el caso que comentas, un valor booleano:

```js
function esMayorQueCero(a){
  if (a > 0){
    return true;
  }
  else{
    return false;
  }
}

console.log(esMayorQueCero(-4));
console.log(esMayorQueCero(4));
```

Habrás visto muchas funciones que devuelven un valor `true` o `false` porque se utilizan mucho en multitud de casos:

- Para realizar validaciones
- Para indicar si un proceso ha tenido éxito
- En controladores de eventos se suele utilizar para indicar si se debe cancelar o no la ejecución del evento
- ....

Por ejemplo puedes asociar un controlador al evento `click` de un link que, si devuelve un valor de `false`, provocará que se anule la navegación:

```js
function navegar(num){
  if (num===2){
    return true;
  }
  else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

```css
a{
  display: block;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://pildorasdotnet.blogspot.com" onclick="return navegar(1);">Este link no funcionará</a>

<a href="http://pildorasdotnet.blogspot.com" onclick="return navegar(2);">Este link sí funcionará</a>
```

Comment: Asier muchas gracias por la explicacion, me podrias hacer el favor de explicarme un poco mejor los casos de uso. Por ejemplo la cancelación de un evento o si un proceso ha tenido éxito. Gracias.

Comment: La cuestión del éxito de un proceso es un tema conceptual: si haces una función que realiza una operación y no devuelve ningún resultado podrías decidir devolver `true` o `false` para indicar al código llamador si la operación se ha podido realizar o no. En cuanto al tema de los eventos, en el DOM puedes asociar a eventos controladores que, si devuelven `false`, cancelan el comportamiento por defecto de éste. Edito la respuesta y te pongo un ejemplo.

Comment: Asier la mejor respuesta muchas gracias.